# KeyError when using Seaborn boxplot with DataFrame

Tags: seaborn, visualization

I'm encountering a KeyError when attempting to create a Seaborn boxplot using a DataFrame in Python. Specifically, when I run the following code:

sns.boxplot(df['built_up_area'].dropna(), color='lightgreen')

I receive the error message:

KeyError: 0

However, I can successfully run a similar code without any errors:

sns.boxplot(df['super_built_up_area'].dropna(), color='lightgreen')

I have verified that the 'built_up_area' column exists in my DataFrame, and I have ensured that there are no non-numeric values in this column. Additionally, I'm using Python with Seaborn version [insert version number] and pandas version [insert version number].

I'm unsure why I'm encountering this KeyError specifically for the 'built_up_area' column. Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

#Step 1: Verify the existence of the 'built_up_area' column
if 'built_up_area' in df.columns:

```
#Step 2: Ensure correct alignment of index positions
#Step 3: Handle missing values before plotting
sns.boxplot(df['built_up_area'].dropna(), color='lightgreen')
```

else:
print("The 'bu  ilt_up_area' column does not exist in the DataFrame.")

Comment: You either need to upgrade seaborn, or use `x=` (or `y=`) in `sns.boxplot(x=df['built_up_area'].dropna(), color='lightgreen')`.